# Is overriding a synthesize property in Objective-C Ok or bad?

Tags: objective-c, synthesize

I have overridden a synthesized property because I wanted to add an NSAssert.

Is this OK to do (i.e override) or considered bad practice?

```
@synthesize someField;

-(NSString*)someField {
    NSAssert(someField != nil,@"someField");
    return someField;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is fine.  From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW14):

> You use the @synthesize keyword to
>   tell the compiler that it should
>   synthesize the setter and/or getter
>   methods for the property if you do not
>   supply them within the @implementation
>   block.

So if you provide them, then the compiler will use yours, irrespective of the @synthesize directive.

Comment: Why would you want to? With the modern (64-bit and iOS) runtime, this is a handy way of creating ivars.

Comment: I think you're talking about implicitly defined ivars which is an entirely different concept.  There are many reasons to provide your own setters and getters, such as permanent storage, database access, caching, etc.

Comment: You're right, I totally misread something here; my comment makes no sense. Thanks for pointing that out for posterity. (Seriously!) :)